# AJAX response has script tags in wrong location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue on a website where a page content (results) are updated via AJAX. Contained within this AJAX returned content is a **script** tag which renders the LinkedIN "share" button.

When the page first loads with the initial resultset the layout looks like this:

[image: Social media controls on page load]

Each of these buttons is within a left-floated **div**, and the HTML looks like this in Chrome developer tools:

[image: HTML on page load]

As you can see the **script** tag is appearing where it is supposed to be, in the **div**, and the dynamically generated **span** containing the button is just above.

Now, when i append more results via an AJAX request, things go a bit haywire, and look like this:

[image: AJAX returned results]

As you can see the LinkedIN button is way out of place, and the reason is apparent when looking at the HTML in developer tools:

[image: HTML from AJAX request]

The **script** tag is not within the **div** where it appears in the code file, instead appearing after the closing **tr** tag - and the **span** with the button is just above.

So, why is this, and more importantly what can be done to ensure that the **script** tag is  where it belongs so that the layout is correct?

FYI - At the foot of the **body** is javascript which loads the LinkedIn .js file and after the AJAX request for more results completes there is an invocation of the LinkedIn .parse() method which is supposed to parse the full document and render the buttons.

**EDIT**

The application is built using ASP.NET MVC and the response returned uses the same .ascx control to format the results as the initial page load does.

**EDIT - AJAX request used to retrieve extra data**

```
function LoadMore(uri, last, loader, end)
{    
    isLoading = true;
    $(loader).show();
    $.post(uri, function(data)
    {
        if (data != "") 
        {
            $(last).after(data);
            isLoading = false;
            // re-do social media share initialisation on the new AJAX-added content
            gapi.plusone.go('container');
            twttr.widgets.load();
            FB.XFBML.parse();
            IN.parse(document.body);
        }
        else
        {
            $(end).show();;
        }
        $(loader).hide();           
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

The actual HTML returned from the server is correct. Viewing the source shows the **script** tag in the correct location, but viewing the page in Chrome developer tools, as shown in the images above, shows the **script** in the wrong place in the DOM. This occurs in both IE9 and Chrome.

Comment: Is that second html-fragment the one actually returned from the server? In that case, it's probably the server side code that needs fixing.

Comment: No. The response is the same .ascx control that is used to display the results in the initial page load.

Comment: Please post the code you're using for the AJAX request itself.

Comment: @krisg so the code sent from the server looks like the first snippet, but when jQuery have inserted it, it looks like the second?

Comment: Tetaxa yep. When the page is loaded the page renders 5 lots of an .ascx control within a foreach loop. When more results are requested via AJAX the same .ascx control is used to render the results to the response. As shown in the HTML screenshots, although the same control is used, the HTML is different with the script tag shoved to the end. Note it still renders 1 script tag for each result in the HTML response... so when the AJAX request asks for 5 more results, it puts the script tag at the end of each foreach iteration - not at the end of the whole HTML response.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building the html dynamically ? Maybe it has something to do with misconfigured callbacks. If you are using $.ajax({...}), make sure that the next iteration is specified into the "success:" property to prevent unordered render.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({ url: 'url',
                type: 'POST',
                data: json,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'text/html',
                success: function (data) {

                    //you response will be data


                }

            });
```